# Can't set pData(eset) <- cbind(pData(eset), test)?

Tags: r, bioconductor

I'm preparing for a differential expression test. I've created an `eset`. The step that I'm currently stuck on is appending a categorical ("control", "mild", etc.) onto a dataframe of disease severity back on to the phenotype data in my `eset`. The categorical values are in a dataframe and were calculated using nested `ifelse()` statements from the pData(eset) dataframe.

The line that keeps breaking is:

```
pData(eset) <- cbind(pData(eset), test_sev)
```

The error I get:

> Error in pData(eset) <- cbind(pData(eset),  :    could not find
> function "pData<-"

I've tried running the `cbind()` alone and it produces the expected results, namely a dataframe of my original `pData(eset)` with a new column called `test_sev` with the appropriate values.

Comment: [This documentation page](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/Biobase/versions/2.32.0/topics/eSet) says that *Adding new columns to `pData` is often more easily done with* `eSetObject[["columnName"]] <- value`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out.  This simply bypasses using the pData function, which seems to be the consensus so far.  Will just append to the eSetObject, then recreate the eset.

Comment: The documentation could be (greatly) improved, apparently `pData<-` is not the way to do it though it is documented. Maybe you should mail the package maintainer.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning the output of a function to the output of a function (no variable is assigned to an output of a function). To make it work, do it in two steps:

```
pheno = pData(eset)
pheno = cbind(pheno, test_sev)
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment - the documentation page suggests that you can set pData so I assumed I was simply missing something.  Will simply bypass as you suggest.